# Asp.net Configration not found in Visual studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

hello my question is where i can find the Asp.net Configuration in VS 2013 Ultimate

in VS 2010 it was available 
Website -> Asp.net Configuration
But i couldn't find this in VS 2013 
Any solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Web Configuration tool was removed from VS2013 for whatever reason, you are still able to access it if you follow these steps:

Open a console (cmd) and paste the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

Open a browser and enter the following, replacing `[Exact_Project_Path]` with your project's path:

```
http://localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=[Exact_Project_Path]\&applicationUrl=/
```

**Note:** When you are finished press 'q' in the console to stop IIS Express